# Preencher DropDownList com Múltiplos Valores

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

eu estou tentando preencher um DropDownList que possui múltilpos valores, a partir da minha action "Edit", onde eu recupero os objeto **ToonMoves** que contém Um ou Mais **Effects** e como Os **Effects** Podem pertencer a vários **ToonMoves**, surgiu um relacionamento **N:N**, conforme a imagem a seguir:

[image: DB Model]

Na minha Action EDIT, eu retorno para a view o objeto **ToonMoves** e na ViewBag os valores do **Effect**

```
        ToonMoves toonMoves = movesService.Get(id.Value);
        ViewBag.Effects = new MultiSelectList(effectsService.GetAll(), "EffectID", "Name", toonMoves.MoveEffects);
        ViewBag.ToonID = new SelectList(toonService.GetAll(), "ToonID", "Name");
        ViewBag.TargetID = new SelectList(targetService.GetAll(), "TargetID", "TargetType", toonMoves.TargetID);
        return View(toonMoves);
```

Observem que já retorno para a ViewBag como MultiSelectList, e na View, está assim:

```
@Html.DropDownList("idsEffects", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Effects, htmlAttributes: new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "selectpicker", data_style = "select-with-transition", title = "Choose Move Effects", data_size = "7" })
```

Porém na View, o campo não vem com nenhum valor selecionado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso fazer com que os valores do objeto **Effects** que estão no Objeto **ToonMoves** aparecem selecionados

[image: Itens Selecionados]

O meu DropDownList tem o nome **"idsEffects"**, pois eu recebo uma lista com os valores em **int**, busco os objetos na tabela **Effects** e adiciono na **MoveEffects**.

Preciso de uma solução para manter esses valores marcados ao carregar a View de Edit, estou disposto a tentar soluções em Jquery, Js, AngularJS... Alguém Pode me ajudar? Se preciso, forneço mais detalhes. Obrigado!

Comment: O que tem na propriedade toonMoves.MoveEffects?

Comment: Contém os IDs do Effects e do ToonMoves, conforme a screenshot: [link](https://www.screenpresso.com/=pV51b)

Comment: E onde você está declarando que esses devem vir selecionados? você precisa levar para a view a lista dos itens que o objeto possui e ao montar o dropdown marcar aqueles que estão contindos nessa lista

Comment: Eu sempre uso com um array passando os id's dos selecionados. Tenta fazer o mesmo, ou tenta passar a propriedade(não sei se funciona, nunca testei). Por exemplo: toonMoves.MoveEffects.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teria que passar na sua `MultiSelectList` os valores que serão selecionados:

```
ViewBag.Effects = new MultiSelectList(effectsService.GetAll(), "EffectID", "Name", new[]{1,2,3} );
```

No caso ele retornaria os itens 1,2 e 3 selecionados.

Referência: [iMasters](https://imasters.com.br/dotnet/asp-net-mvc-5-dropdownlist-com-selecao-multipla)

Essa seria a implementação do método:

```
public MultiSelectList(
  IEnumerable items,
  string dataValueField,
  string dataTextField,
  IEnumerable selectedValues
)
```

Comment: Obrigado, amigo, tive que percorrer um laço para obter os ID's e então enviei para a Multiselectlist e funcionou.